# Exception: Unsupported Android Plugin version: 4.1.2

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I know this might have been asked before, I have recently installed Solus Linux on my computer and I am trying to get Andoird Studio working on it for some time, so far I am not having any luck.
First Issue - I am not able to add Flutter to the PATH
Second Issue - I am getting this error when running the project
[image]

Could somebody here help me with both issues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think at the moment, there is a problem of incompatible version.

Reference: from this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49438)

To fix it, I **revert back Android Plugin from 4.1.2 to 4.1.0**.

Modify the root build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.20'
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    ...
  }
}
```

Note: I, currently, use Gradle 6.7

Comment: I was getting errors in the 4.2.0 gradle. When I change it to 4.1.0 it works Note that it's not working on 4.1.2

Answer (score 86):

Maybe it can help future devs. I had similar problem with the exception

> Unsupported Android Plugin version 4.1.3

In my case I had to specify build flavor for the app:

```
flutter run --flavor <flavor-name>
```

then it worked

Comment: +1 Could not figure out why my CI pipeline did not pass and realized I had meanwhile introduce Android flavors. Local builds worked fine for me but forgot to update my CI script (GH actions) to include `--flavor` argument, after that it worked fine.

Comment: what is the `flavor-name` that we need to pass?

Comment: fixed thanks ...

Comment: should be marked as accepted

Comment: Flavors are defined in `android/gradle/build.gradle.`

Comment: this worked! Crazy how the error message is giving no information at about the real issue. I spent hours being mislead by that error message. I mean, how are we supposed to guess that "Unsupported Android Plugin version: 4.1.2" means "you forgot to include the flavor name buddy"

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Doing this solved my problem

- Added `dev` as Build flavor
- Added `--debug` as Additional build args

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to edit my configuration settings:

1. go to "Edit configurations"
2. choose the config you're trying to run
3. fill in the "Build flavor" accordingly

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

if your are performing integration test in flutter with flavors then you should run this command to test
`flutter drive --flavor dev \ --driver=test_driver/integration_driver.dart \ --target=integration_test/login_page/login_integration_test.dart`

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was about the flavor configuration. I have main, develop, and production flavors I haven't set up configuration for main so when main is selected this error is happened

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it  by changing the "splits" property to enable = false, in the build.gradle. When we release to production that property is set to true, so i just forgot to set it on false again.

Should be something like this:

```
splits {
        // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
        abi {
            // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
            enable false

            // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
            reset()

            // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
            include 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a'

            // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk false
        }
    }
```